# Оптимизировать алгоритм поиска простых числе в заданном диапазоне

Tags: java, простые-числа

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно оптимизировать мой алгоритм. (Нужно посчитать все простые числа в промежутке от n до 2 n).

И появляется

> time limit exceeded.

**Код**

```
package com.company;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = read.readLine();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(s);

        int p = 0;
        for (int i = n; i <= 2 * n; i++) {
            Integer res = i;
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    res = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (res != null && res > n) {
                p++;

            }
        }
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Какие входящие данные вы используете? Вроде ваш код работает.

Comment: он работает, но на сайте куда нужно закинуть для проверки, он не проходит по времени. Оно не должно превышать 1 секунду. входящие данные от 2 до 50000

Comment: во втором цикле можно перебирать до квадратного корня числа. `for (int j = 2; j * j <= i; j++)`

Comment: Получается другой ответ на тестах - неверный(

Comment: Вы можете делать поиск числа с помощью деления без остатка до корня из числа.

Answer (score 1):

Нет необходимости проверять **каждое** число диапазона. Четные числа можно и нужно пропускать. Поэтому в самом начале нужно сделать проверку числа `n` на четность и в зависимости от результата начинать с `n` или c `n+1` и идти с шагом 2:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
if isEven(n){
    start = n+1;
} else {
    start = n;
}

for (int i = start; i <= 2 * n; i += 2)
```

Далее, не совсем понятно что делает участок

```
if (res != null && res > n) {
    p++;
}
```

Ну и выводите вы одно единственное число `p`, хотя нужно вывести все простые числа из диапазона.

Comment: Нужно посчитать все простые числа, а не выводить их. `p` - это как раз счетчик